# Nesting if/else statements in CodeAcademy's Rock, Paper, Scissors excercise

Tags: javascript

I'm getting kind of confused on 6/9 of CodeAcademy's Rock Paper Scissors excercise. All I know right now is that there's three options, rock, paper, scissors. I have to log all the outcomes of the game. On 6/9 I'm asked to nest if/else statements and this was my submission:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return("The result is a tie!"); }
}; if (choice1 == "rock") {
   } if (choice2 == "scissors") {
        return ("rock wins");
} else { 
    return ("paper wins");
};
```

For some reason it's telling me that there's a problem with my syntax and that 'return is not in function'. I also don't really understand the nesting of the if statements. Surely it should be if, elseif and then else?

I'd appreciate any clarity on the excercise if you'd be so kind. I genuinely can't get my head around this really simple excercise and it's stressing me out. I could just input some answer from the CodeAcademy Q and A but then I wouldn't understand it.

Comment: You should indent your code better. http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html. Do that and you will see the problem :)

Comment: You should include all the conditions into the function. As already suggested use proper code formatting and please also use some sort of debugging tool for JS.

Answer (score 1):

Good that you're trying to learn (keep it up !), make sure you indent your code properly:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie";
    }

    if(choice1 === "rock") {
        if(choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "Rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
    }
    // you get the idea
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay for awhile this confused me and it's because I was misunderstanding how {} worked and after doing a little tweaking this felt smoother and easier to understand for me

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
if(choice1 === choice2) 
{return "The result is a tie!";}

else if(choice1 === "rock") 
    if (choice2 === "scissors") 
    {return "rock wins";}
    else 
    {return "paper wins";}
else if (choice1 === "paper")
    if (choice2 === "rock")
    {return "paper wins";}
    else
    {return "scissors wins";}
else if (choice1 === "scissors")
    if (choice2 === "rock")
    {return "rock wins";}
    else
    {return "scissors wins";}
 };
```

by moving the {} to one line I was able to see how it all worked, it's not recommended but it definitely helped me visualize brackets and how it relates in the code. Good luck and glad to see I'm not the only one that struggled there!