# How to count the results in a for loop?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to count the number of times I won and the number of times the computer won in the game of "Rock Paper and Scissors." I've created global variables, "ComputerWon" and "YouWon," and did the following:

```
    //Counting

    if (userGuess == computerGuess) {
       i--; 
    }
    else if (userGuess < computerGuess) {
       ComputerWon++;
       System.out.println("You lost..");
    } 
    else if (userGuess > computerGuess) {
        System.out.println("You won!");
    }

    }
   System.out.println("Computer won " + ComputerWon + "times");
```

Could someone point out the flaw in my logic? It doesn't execute the way I want. Thanks!
Anya

Comment: please add the log error it will help to improve your question

Comment: Where do you intcrement the YouWon variable? What is i? Where is the loop you are talking about

Comment: What do you expect, your code should do? What does your code do, what are the results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting if/else statements in CodeAcademy's Rock, Paper, Scissors excercise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904088/nesting-if-else-statements-in-codeacademys-rock-paper-scissors-excercise)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my question. I put my variables inside the for loop and didn't declare them outside (global).